# Is there a way to typecheck boolean expressions using the Scala compiler?

Tags: scala, parsing, typechecking, parser-combinators

I am currently building a parser using Scala parser combinators. The parser must accept boolean expressions which at the moment I am type checking and evaluating manually. However, I want to extend this particular feature and be able to accept more complex boolean expressions which would require more manual work. I was wondering whether the typechecking could be achieved using directly the Scala compiler, to which I would pass the particular expression that I want to be typechecked and the types of each particular variable. Below is an example of what I mean:

Assume that I have a boolean expression: `age > 18`. Together with a mapping knowing that the variable `age` is of type `Int`. I want to be able to pass (in any format) `age > 18` and the type mappings to the Scala compiler, and it will return whether it typechecks to a boolean expression or not.

Comment: Link to OP's post at reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/ewsn9g/is_there_a_way_to_typecheck_boolean_expressions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Courtesy of [u/aepurniet](https://www.reddit.com/user/aepurniet/) from [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/ewsn9g/is_there_a_way_to_typecheck_boolean_expressions/) Reddit post.

The statement must be prefixed to the statement with some value definitions, then parse and then type checked. The resultant type of the expression can be checked from `checked.tpe`.

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  import scala.reflect.runtime._
  import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
  val toolbox = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
  val expr = "age > 18"
  val eval = s"""
     |val age: Int = ???
     |$expr
     |""".stripMargin
  val tree = toolbox.parse(eval)
  val checked = toolbox.typecheck(tree)
  println(checked.tpe)
}
```

Comment: The statement doesn't have to be prefixed with definitions. You can use imports as well: `"import ...; $expr"`.